# Add field to JSON object and append in POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

I currently have a json like this in my activities column:

```
{"event": "car race", "effectiveFrom": "2020-05-13T10:50:00Z"}
```

Then I would like to update this value to this:

```
[
    {"event": "car race", "effectiveFrom": "2020-05-13T10:50:00Z", effectiveTo:"2021-05-13T10:50:00Z"},
    {"event": "walking race", "effectiveFrom": "2021-05-13T10:50:00Z"}
]
```

So essentially I will need to convert the json to an array, add a field of effectiveTo to the existing object and add a new object.

I have been able to add the effectiveTo field to the existing object like so:

```
UPDATE event_races
SET activities = JSON_MODIFY(activities,'$.effectiveTo',time.Now().UTC())
```

However, since I also have to append a new object as well to the existing JSON I am not sure how to do that within the 1 query. Any tips? Is that possible?

Comment: JSON_MODIFY is ms sql server database function...

Comment: You can't be using Postgres if that UPDATE statement works for you. Which DBMS are you really using?